# Getting broken response while posting barclays form through Karate

Tags: karate

I need to process a test order through Barclays. For that, I need to send some data which is an HTML form like below:
I tried storing  form in a variable like below:
Given URL 'https://test.barclaycardsmartpay.com/hpp/pay.shtml'

```
def data = { billingAddress.city: "##",billingAddress.country: "#", billingAddress.HouseNumberOrName: "##",billingAddress.postalCode: "##",billingAddress.stateOrProvince: "##",billingAddress.street: "N/A",billingAddressType: "#",countryCode: "UK",currencyCode: "GBP",deliveryAddress.city: "##",deliveryAddress.country: "GB",deliveryAddress.houseNumberOrName: "##",deliveryAddress.postalCode: "##",deliveryAddress.stateOrProvince: "##",deliveryAddress.street: 'N/A',deliveryAddressType:"",merchantAccount: "##",merchantReference:"#(order)",voucherHashKey:0,merchantReturnData: "",paymentAmount: "#(totalCost)",resURL: "https://#.#.##.##.#/buy/process",SessionValidity:"#(val)",shipBeforeDate: "#(shipDate)",shopperLocale: "en_GB",skinCode:"##",merchantSig:"#(sig)"} // tried without quote
```

form fields data 
When method post 
Then status 200
I always get the broken response saying 'Unfortunately we are unable to process the request.' This is the form where the user needs to pass the card info and process the order through Barclays. I am passing some values through which are the responses from other API's like merchantSig, value, etc.
If someone has any insight, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea about "Barclays" but your JSON looks bad. I am not going to read all of it but just a suggestion below:

```
* def data = { billingAddress: { city: "##", country: "##" } }
```

See the difference with what you posted and try fixing it. My sincere suggestion is please pair up with someone in your same org (or a friend who has time) who can help you because from your previous questions I think you need to get a little more comfortable with JSON itself and some basic fundamentals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I modified the JSON but still getting a broken response  like below:
[Fatal Error] :84:101: The value of the attribute "value" associated with an element type "input" must not contain the '<' character. 

Can we avoid above  HTML tags using karate? Like here Barclays throws the above error which Karate accepts as the fatal error. I checked with developers about the forms data and which are fine.  @peterThomas

Comment: @RanjanGupta sorry I have no idea about "Barclays". why don't you get this working in something like Postman first ? that will be a better use of your time.

Comment: I tried with Postman but no luck with it. Can Karate filter HTML tags? I asked dev on the issue and they said that ask Karate dev how to avoid HTML tags coz that is the fatal error I have got.

Comment: the Karate dev is replying that the question does not make any sense and if there is no luck with Postman, there is no use in advancing to Karate. the Karate dev also wishes the whole team luck because they need lots of it